# Two Solution for a Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation-

$$x^2y'' - (x^2 + 2x)y' + (x+2)y = x^3e^x$$

There are two possible solutions to this differential equation -

$$y_1 = c_1x + c_2xe^x + x^2e^x $$
$$y_2 = c_1x + c_2xe^x + x^2e^x - xe^x$$

Both these solutions ([$y_1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex)%27%27+-+(x%5E2+%2B+2x)(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex)%27+%2B+(x%2B2)(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex)) and [$y_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex+-+xe%5Ex)%27%27+-+(x%5E2+%2B+2x)(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex+-+xe%5Ex)%27+%2B+(x%2B2)(ax+%2B+bxe%5Ex+%2B+x%5E2e%5Ex+-+xe%5Ex))) satisfy the given differential equation. The difference between these two solutions is not of an arbitrary constant but of a term containing x.

I am not able to understand what does this mean. Can a differential equation have more than one solutions?

Comment: For $y_2$, let $k_2=c_2-1$, where $k_2$ is another *arbitrary* constant.

Comment: Thanks... couldn't notice it earlier.